# Quel est le sens de « bœufs-carottes » dans cet article ?

Tags: traduction, sens, vocabulaire

Chaque matin je lis *Le Monde* pour améliorer mon français et ce matin il y a l'article :

> [Chez les policiers, peu de mansuétude pour les "bœufs-carottes" mis en cause](http://www.lemonde.fr/cgi-bin/ACHATS/acheter.cgi?offre=ARCHIVES&type_item=ART_ARCH_30J&objet_id=1179445&xtmc=boeuf_carottes&xtcr=1)

Je comprends que l'article est un rapport sur la corruption policière, et que « la mansuétude » veut dire « tolerance » après un sens en anglais, alors comme traduction je comprends :

> Intolerance of [?] blamed (for corruption)

qui me semble incorrect. Alors, en lisant l'article, j'ai cherché à deviner — je me demande si :

> Little respect for getting the basics right blamed for police corruption

vaut mieux. Alors, ma question : est-ce que « les bœufs-carottes » veut dire « the basics » dans ce sens? Comme « bread and butter » veut dire « the basics » en Anglais ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Bœufs-carottes* is French slang for *Internal Affairs investigators*. It's actually explained in the linked article:

> Ses membres triés sur le volet par la hiérarchie, sont surnommés les "bœufs-carottes" et plus fréquemment "les bœufs" par les autres policiers. Les fonctionnaires de l’IGS ne sont pas particulièrement appréciés de leurs collègues. Ils ont la réputation d’être inflexibles, d’être peu portés à l’indulgence, voire d’instruire à charge les procédures disciplinaires.

So the title roughly means:

> Policemen won't cry much for accused Internal Affairs investigators

Answer (score 9):

Le terme *bœuf-carottes* désigne l'[IGPN](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inspection_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rale_de_la_police_nationale), aussi appelée *police des polices*, le service de la police nationale chargé de contrôler le bon fonctionnement des services de police

> Composés de commissaires et d'officiers de police, les enquêteurs de l'IGPN sont surnommés par les autres policiers les « bœuf-carottes » ou tout simplement les « bœufs » , surnom donné pour leur réputation de « cuisiner » longtemps les personnes interrogées par leurs services.
>   (**[Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inspection_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rale_de_la_police_nationale#Les_.C2.AB_b.C5.93uf-carottes_.C2.BB)**)

[Cuisiner](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cuisiner) signifiant ici *mener un interrogatoire poussé*.

Answer (score 1):

## Les "[bœufs-carottes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inspection_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rale_de_la_Police_nationale#Les_%C2%AB_b%C5%93uf-carottes_%C2%BB)" désignent les fonctionnaires de "la police des polices".

Comme son nom l'indique, sa mission est de "faire la police dans la police" et de veiller au respect des [règles](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_de_d%C3%A9ontologie_de_la_Police_nationale_et_de_la_Gendarmerie_nationale) régissant la [profession](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_nationale_(France)).

Réputés pour faire "mijoter" leurs collègues en auditions, les "bœuf-carottes" ou "bœuf" sont répartis en deux services qui se distinguent essentiellement par leur zone d'intervention :

- l'IGS (inspection générale des services, aujourd'hui fusionnée avec l'[Inspection générale de la Police nationale](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inspection_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rale_de_la_Police_nationale)) dépend de la [préfecture de police de Paris](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9fecture_de_police_de_Paris), est compétente sur Paris et les trois départements de la [Petite Couronne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petite_couronne_de_Paris) ([Hauts-de-Seine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hauts-de-Seine) (92), [Seine-Saint-Denis](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seine-Saint-Denis) (93), [Val-de-Marne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Val-de-Marne) (94)).
- l'[IGPN (inspection générale de la police nationale)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inspection_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rale_de_la_Police_nationale) intervient sur le reste du territoire et est rattachée à la [direction générale de la police nationale](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rale_de_la_Police_nationale) qui dépend du [ministère de l'Intérieur](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minist%C3%A8re_de_l%27Int%C3%A9rieur_(France)). Basée à Paris, elle a deux antennes régionales à Lyon et Marseille.

Les personnels et les activités de la [Gendarmerie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gendarmerie_nationale_(France)), ne sont pas concernés par l'IGPN, mais par l'[inspection générale de la Gendarmerie nationale](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inspection_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rale_de_la_Gendarmerie_nationale) qui remplit un rôle identique.

> [Amnesty international](https://www.amnesty.org/fr/documents/EUR21/003/2009/fr/), le [Comité anti-torture du Conseil de l'Europe](http://archive.wikiwix.com/cache/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cpt.coe.int%2Fdocuments%2Ffra%2F2012-04-19-fra.htm), l'[ONU via la Convention internationale sur l'élimination de toutes les formes de discrimination raciale](http://www.un.org/press/fr/2005/DR987.doc.htm) ainsi que le [World Justice Project](https://worldjusticeproject.org/our-work/publications/rule-law-index-reports/wjp-rule-law-index-2012-2013-report) accusent la France d'impunité policière.